# Geometry nodes: Split edges if faces only connected by 1 vertex

Tags: geometry-nodes

Completely stumped by this.

I want to split my geometry, so faces need to share at least two vertexes.

Here's an image of what I'm trying to achieve. Notice, the faces that are connected by just corners are split away.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Just a hint, no perfect solution: you can split the faces with a *Separate Geometry* node. This needs a selection. As selection criteria, you can use the number of neighboring faces (*Face Neighbors > Face Count* is greater than 0). After this, join the geometry again. This works for your example. But it fails when you have 2 or more single faces that only share 1 vertex, because they all have 0 neighbor faces and you cannot distinguish them to separate them. *Bummer* :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\hspace{15pt}$If I understood you correctly, you want to disconnect faces that share a single vertex from each other.

$\hspace{15pt}$To do that, simply check if the edge has only one face connected before splitting:

[image]

---

$\hspace{15pt}$In this next image you can see that they are indeed separated, they have a random color and are being translated by a random noise per mesh island.

[image]